# PHP REST API query returning empty body

Tags: php, mysql, api, slim

I cannot get my PHP Rest API to work, it is just returning empty body
with a successful HTTP request(200).

When I just echo something out it returns it fine.  I am using Slim (PHP micro framework), `MySQL`,`apache`. Database table is created in phpmyadmin.

**index.php**

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../src/config/db.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Hello, $name");

    return $response;
});

// Customer Routes
require '../src/routes/dates.php';

$app->run();
```

**db.php** it also contains dbhost, dbuser, dbpass and dbname
 variables above

```
<?php
class db
{
    // Properties
    var $dbhost = 'localhost';
    var $dbuser = 'root';
    var $dbpass = 'parool1';
    var $dbname = 'slimapp';

    // Connect
    public function connect()
    {
        $mysql_connect_str = "mysql:host=$this->dbhost;dbname=$this->dbname";
        $dbConnection = new PDO($mysql_connect_str, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        $dbConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return $dbConnection;
    }
}
```

**dates.php**

```
<?php

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

// Get All Calendar Dates
$app->get('/api/date', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `calendardates`";

    try {
        // Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $dates = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($dates);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error": {"text": ' . $e->getMessage() . '}';
    }
});
```

[image: File Structure:]
 [image: Empty Body]
**Solution:**

Change collation of database table to utf8 (if you want to use charcaters like "ö, ä, ü" in your database table).

I changed

```
$dbConnection = new PDO($mysql_connect_str, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
```

to

```
$dbConnection = new PDO($mysql_connect_str, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

to fix the problem.

Comment: could you add  `var_dump($dates)`  outputs?

Comment: did you tried `return $response->withJson($dates)` ?

Comment: var_dump($dates) returns: array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#65 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["date_title"]=> string(9) "Nuudip�ev" ["date_date"]=> string(10) "1515283200" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#66 (3) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["date_title"]=> string(13) "Taliharjap�ev" ["date_date"]=> string(10) "1515888000" } }

Answer (score 0):

To return a json try to replace

```
echo json_encode($dates);
```

With

```
return $response->withJson($dates);
```

As suggested by mim in comment.